# Почему ставится запятая в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нанесенное перед укладкой, масло предохраняет мокрые волосы от пересыхания и повреждения горячим воздухом фена или жаром стайлера.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая здесь будет стоять, если определение имеет добавочное обстоятельственное значение.

[Розенталь, § 18](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108) (см. пункт 8):

> Распространенное или одиночное определение, стоящее непосредственно
> перед существительным, обособляется, если оно имеет добавочное
> обстоятельственное значение (причинное, условное, уступительное и т.
> п.): *Усталые до последней степени, альпинисты не могли продолжить своё
> восхождение* — на определительное значение (какие альпинисты?; ср. без
> обособления: *Усталые до последней степени альпинисты…*) наслаивается
> причинное значение (почему не могли продолжить свое восхождение?);
> *Предоставленные самим себе, дети окажутся в трудном положении* — здесь
> важно не столько определительное значение (какие дети?; ср. без
> обособления: *Предоставленные самим себе дети…*), сколько
> обстоятельственное — условное (при каком условии окажутся в трудном
> положении?); *Обычно спокойный, оратор на этот раз сильно волновался* —
> здесь не только дается характеристика человека (какой оратор?; ср. без
> обособления: *Обычно спокойный оратор…*), но и вносится уступительный
> оттенок значения (‘вопреки тому, что он обычно спокоен…’). Во всех
> подобных случаях определительный оборот легко заменяется придаточной
> частью сложноподчиненного предложения: причинной (*…потому что устали
> до последней степени*), условной (*…дети будут предоставлены самим
> себе*), уступительной (*…хотя он обычно спокоен*) и т. п.